# How to convert an IPv6 address to a binary string?

Tags: java, binary, network-programming, ipv6, data-conversion

How to convert an IPv6 address to a binary string?

Example:

```
IPv6:    2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
Binary:  0010000000000001 0000110110111000 1000010110100011 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 1000101000101110 0000001101110000 0111001100110100
```

---

I want to do this in Java. Here is my failed attempt (I do not ask for a solution related to this attempt whatsoever):

Implemented in C++, where I am more familiar:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

std::string toBinary(unsigned long int decimalIpV6)
{
    std::string r;
    while(decimalIpV6!=0) {r=(decimalIpV6%2==0 ?"0":"1")+r; decimalIpV6/=2;}
    return r;
}

unsigned long int ipV6toDecimal(std::string binaryString) {
    struct sockaddr_in antelope;    
    inet_aton(binaryString.c_str(), &antelope.sin_addr); // store IP in antelope
    // and this call is the same as the inet_aton() call, above:
    antelope.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(binaryString.c_str());
    return antelope.sin_addr.s_addr;
}

int main() {
    std::string ipv6 = "192.168.0.0";
    unsigned long int ipv6decimal= ipV6toDecimal(ipv6);
    std::cout << toBinary(ipv6decimal) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which is buggy and produces a wrong result ("1010100011000000").

---

PS: There is an IPv6 to Binary calculator [online](https://www.easycalculation.com/other/ipv6-to-binary.php), which might help you when testing.

Comment: `I want to do this in Java. Here is my failed attempt` ... uhm...

Comment: Yeah @Henrik, it would be bad if I didn't try it myself first!

Comment: Sure, that's the spirit, but it doesn't seem to be included. :) Only your working C++ version.

Comment: I could translate that to Java, but it would still be a failure @Henrik :/ Thanks for pointing it out though, question edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution :

```
String ipv6 = "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334";
String[] spl = ipv6.split(":");
String result = "", del = "";
for (String s : spl) {
    result += del
            + String.format("%16s", new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2)).replace(' ', '0');
    del = " ";
}
System.out.println(result);
```

---

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
String result = Stream.of(ipv6.split(":"))
      .map(s -> String.format("%16s", new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2)).replace(' ', '0'))
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Output

```
0010000000000001 0000110110111000 1000010110100011 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 1000101000101110 0000001101110000 0111001100110100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way:

```
String ipv6 = "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334";
String result = "";
for (String s : ipv6.split(":")) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
    result += String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(value)).replace(' ', '0') + " ";
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
0010000000000001 0000110110111000 1000010110100011 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 1000101000101110 0000001101110000 0111001100110100
```

**EDIT**

The previous solution won't work when the given IPv6 address is compressed. For example `3210:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` can be shortened to `3210::` and is worth to mention that in those cases the solutions proposed so far won't work if we don't handle this first. To solve that issue you can do this:

```
String ipv6CompressedAddress = "3210::";
Inet6Address ipv6Address = (Inet6Address) Inet6Address.getByName(ipv6CompressedAddress);
String ipv6 = ipv6Address.getCanonicalHostName(); // 3210:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
```

Here I'm using [Java's IPv6 representation class Inet6Address](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) to get a less compressed ip address. Then we can use the methods shown earlier to convert it to binary.

Comment: Thanks Juan, but I am going to accept the other answer, because it arrived first. Thank you also for your upvote!

Comment: The mixed mode (`2001:0db8::10.11.12.13) is also valid and should be considered.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for pointing it out. That mode is also supported.

Answer (score 2):

The [open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can produce many different string formats, one of them being a binary string.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the IPAddress library.

```
String str = "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334";

IPAddressString addrStr = new IPAddressString(str);
IPAddress addr  = addrStr.getAddress();
String binaryStr = addr.toBinaryString();
System.out.println(binaryStr);
```

Output:

```
00100000000000010000110110111000100001011010001100000000000000000000000000000000100010100010111000000011011100000111001100110100
```

Note that this handles the various different ways of representing IPv6 addresses (such as with compressed segments, or with embedded IPv4 as final segments).  Also note the code works equally well for IPv4 addresses.